# SSRS - Number format expression not working

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I have a table in my database called systemconfig which has some configs that I'll use on my reports. The idea is, instead of adjusting the 'number formats' directly in the textboxes properties of the report, I just change a value in this table, and then through a custom expression in the format property, it gets the value from this table

The query of the dataset 'ds_DecimalValues' is like this:

```
DECLARE @DecimalValue Nvarchar(500)
SELECT @DecimalValue = 
 ( SELECT Value as 'DecimalValue' FROM SystemConfig WHERE Key = Decimal_Value )

SELECT
    DecimalValue = @DecimalValue
```

ok, the result of this query is ##

In the textbox properties I have this expression in the Format line:

```
=First(Fields!DecimalValue.Value, "ds_DecimalValue")
```

But the report is showing 2 decimal values instead of none. I'm not sure if the decimal values are correct on the systemconfig table, I assume that '##' is correct to show no decimal values but I'm not sure about it. Any ideas guys??

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

When I have done this in the past I would typically use someting like `f0` or `n0` as the format code.

Try using this instead of `##`.

If this does not work then a couple of things to debug.

1. Add a textbox that contains the same expression as you are using in your format property expression, make sure it is returning what you expect
2. Type the format code directly in and make sure that it formats as you expected.

remember that you don't need to use quotes when using codes like `f0` etc.

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this work for you? Should round it to the nearest integer

```
=Floor(First(Fields!DecimalValue.Value, "ds_DecimalValue"))
```

Comment: Unfortunately it not worked :( 

Actually the idea is if the decimalvalue on the table systemconfig is '##', it should show no decimal values, however if it is '##.##', it should show 2 decimal values and so on. But none of them are working.